# No root page found in Contao CMS

Tags: contao

I have a web application that is running smoothly on remote server. But for enhancements, I have to run the application in local server. But when I try to load the front end preview of the application, It says 'No root page found'.

Comment: Which Contao version are you running? You should answer the obvious first: does your site have a root page? If yes, does it have a domain specified?

Comment: I am using the Contao version of 3.4.5. And yes It has root page specified and It is working fine in remote server. I have cloned the exact copy of application files and tried to develop a module in local server. And the application displays the error message once I load the front-end preview.

Comment: Have you set a specific URL for your root page? This is mostly used for multi installs. If so it will fail because your local server does not match this URL.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the `domain name` in the `site root` page is empty or is corresponding with the live domain?

Other possibility is activating the `language fallback` checkbox on the `site root` page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your warning messages or screenshots ?

I met this situations like this before, because Contao is running in maintenance mode .

So i put this line on localconfig.php

```
$GLOBALS['TL_CONFIG']['maintenanceMode'] = false;
```

And it runs.